# Is there a way to debug a mapping template in aws apigateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I am trying to create a apigateway mapping template, that transforms this:

```
{
    "ref": "refs/heads/master"
}
```

into this:

```
{
    "download_url":"http://example.com/master"
}
```

So I tried this:

```
{
  "branch": $input.path($.ref).substring($input.path($.ref).lastIndexOf('/')+1)
}
```

Testing this method I get a simple error:

```
Execution failed due to configuration error: Unable to transform request
```

Now, of course I would like to know why this failed. But more importantly: How can I debug this? Is there anyway to get a more describing error message for a mapping template?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not with API Gateway directly, but since API Gateway uses the [Velocity template engine](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/devel/index.html) under the hood you might consider downloading and running the velocity engine on your own computer to debug your templates.

Comment: Ok, that I can do. Maybe you jave an Idea of the best way to do it? As I can see it velocity is a java library. Is  there a simple executable with which I can test my templates?